# ROS rgbdslam not working as expected

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, roslaunch, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's my first time with ros and I installed using the [RGB-D SLAM for "Not-yet" ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) Users (bottom of the page)

I'm able to run the following but no GUI shows up so after a few minutes of sitting there I `ctrl+c`. Am I missing something?

```
$ roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch
... logging to /home/jackson/.ros/log/65d80698-bc6b-11e5-a420-000c29347746/roslaunch-ubuntu-4488.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:55220/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/depth/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/min_range
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /rgbdslam/config/backend_solver
 * /rgbdslam/config/feature_detector_type
 * /rgbdslam/config/feature_extractor_type
 * /rgbdslam/config/g2o_transformation_refinement
 * /rgbdslam/config/gicp_max_cloud_size
 * /rgbdslam/config/icp_method
 * /rgbdslam/config/max_keypoints
 * /rgbdslam/config/min_matches
 * /rgbdslam/config/min_rotation_degree
 * /rgbdslam/config/min_sampled_candidates
 * /rgbdslam/config/min_time_reported
 * /rgbdslam/config/min_translation_meter
 * /rgbdslam/config/neighbor_candidates
 * /rgbdslam/config/nn_distance_ratio
 * /rgbdslam/config/observability_threshold
 * /rgbdslam/config/octomap_online_creation
 * /rgbdslam/config/octomap_resolution
 * /rgbdslam/config/predecessor_candidates
 * /rgbdslam/config/ransac_iterations
 * /rgbdslam/config/store_pointclouds
 * /rgbdslam/config/topic_image_depth
 * /rgbdslam/config/topic_image_mono
 * /rgbdslam/config/topic_points
 * /rgbdslam/config/use_icp
 * /rgbdslam/config/visualization_skip_step
 * /rgbdslam/config/visualize_keyframes_only
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /camera/depth/
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    points (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/rgb/
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgbdslam (rgbdslam/rgbdslam)
  /camera/
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/ir/
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth_registered/
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)

WARNING: [/home/jackson/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/launch/kinect+rgbdslam.launch] unknown <node> attribute 'no-launch-prefix'
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4504]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 65d80698-bc6b-11e5-a420-000c29347746
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4517]
started core service [/rosout]
process[camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [4529]
process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [4530]
[ INFO] [1452960516.664546337]: Initializing nodelet with 2 worker threads.
process[camera/rgb/debayer-4]: started with pid [4567]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-5]: started with pid [4586]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-6]: started with pid [4602]
process[camera/ir/rectify_ir-7]: started with pid [4618]
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-8]: started with pid [4633]
process[camera/depth/metric_rect-9]: started with pid [4650]
process[camera/depth/metric-10]: started with pid [4666]
process[camera/depth/points-11]: started with pid [4690]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-12]: started with pid [4706]
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [4732]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-14]: started with pid [4756]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric-15]: started with pid [4779]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-16]: started with pid [4798]
process[camera/disparity_depth-17]: started with pid [4821]
process[camera/disparity_depth_registered-18]: started with pid [4834]
process[camera_base_link-19]: started with pid [4852]
process[camera_base_link1-20]: started with pid [4868]
process[camera_base_link2-21]: started with pid [4882]
process[camera_base_link3-22]: started with pid [4904]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rgbdslam/rgbdslam]: can't locate node [rgbdslam] in package [rgbdslam]
[ INFO] [1452960518.568452622]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1452960518.568705891]: 1. device on bus 001:04 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00363914834133A'
[ INFO] [1452960518.569645724]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1452960518.649156529]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:4 with serial number 'A00363914834133A'
[ INFO] [1452960518.676101914]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1452960518.676375212]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1452960518.681387988]: Camera calibration file /home/jackson/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00363914834133A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1452960518.681472281]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1452960518.681506199]: Camera calibration file /home/jackson/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00363914834133A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1452960518.681527988]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

NOTE [here is an issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/224273/siftgpu-cannot-be-compiled/) I ran into before getting to this point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224270/ros-rgbdslam-not-working-as-expected/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srik11](https://answers.ros.org/users/25636/srik11/) on 2016-01-17**:
Hi!,
Which sensor are you using? Is it the new kinect (Kinect for xbox one). I have tried using the new kinect but facing some issues with the usb port. I have been using the usb 3.0 port. But somehow cannot get the data from kinect.
Wanted to know your inputs on how you got to run the kinect.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-01-18**:
@srik11 I'm using the old kinect for xbox 360 on USB 3. It works with freenect but not with rgbdslam (yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you use openni, you can use this one:

roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) with karma: 113 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-01-18**:
This works but for some reason my camera isn't connecting..

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-01-28**:
This wasn't working on my mac VM (ubuntu 12.04 amd64) but worked on a crappy HP laptop I bought (ubuntu 12.04.05 i386)